# Run asp mvc 3 in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed visual studio 2010, etc. and began an asp mvc3 project a while ago. Right now i want to install it in iis, so that other people can see it in a local network. Does anybody have any links for this information, and steps? This is a school project, i have to run it in different computers to show it.

Thanks!

**Additional info:** The IIS version that was installed is IIS 7

Comment: The version that i have is IIS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept also a video learning + IIS Express, then I can strongly recommend [**this presentation by Scott Hanselman**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM02) from MIX11, he's showing how to setup IIS Express for MVC 3 Application (among many useful tips about asp.net mvc 3 generally).

Answer (score 0):

FOR IIS 6, this is the best resource > http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx